# PHP, replacing array variable with other array variables

Tags: php, arrays

Here's sample code:

```
$array1 = array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3");
$array2 = array("Name2" => "NameX");
foreach($array1 as $val) 
{
    echo $val."<br/>";
}
```

This would output:
Name1
Name2
Name3

How can I output this instead:
Name1
NameX
Name3

**Yogesh Suthar** submitted the correct reply:

```
 $array1 = array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3");

$array2 = array("Name2" => "NameX");
foreach($array1 as $val) {
    if (array_key_exists($val, $array2)) {
            echo $array2[$val];
    }
    else {
            echo $val."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will take your question literally & use the code you have.

```
$array1 = array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3");
$array2 = array("Name2" => "NameX");
foreach($array1 as $val) {
    if (array_key_exists($val, $array2)) {
            echo $array2[$val]."<br/>";
    }
    else {
            echo $val."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This one literally answers your question, but again... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's perfect, thanks. I can't mark it as correct yet. I'm using this code to replace names from database with other names (if it's in the array). Perfect.

Comment: One addition, how would I replace a single variable with it's array key? Like $var = "Name2"; $array = array("Name2" => "NameX"); str_replace($var, $array"), doesn't work, and the array will have multiple values

Comment: `$var = $array[$var];` i guess. but be careful. that would just work if $array has the key "Name2"

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for array_replace()

```
<?php
$base = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$replacements = array(0 => "pineapple", 4 => "cherry");
$replacements2 = array(0 => "grape");

$basket = array_replace($base, $replacements, $replacements2);
print_r($basket);
?>
```

it will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => grape
    [1] => banana
    [2] => apple
    [3] => raspberry
    [4] => cherry
)
```

[PHP: array_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($a1 as $v) {
  if (isset($a2[v]) && !empty($a2[$v]))
    echo "{$a2[$val]}<br />";
  else
    echo "$val<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $array1 = array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3");
enter code here$array2 = array("Name2" => "NameX");

//Loop tthrough replacement array 
foreach($array2 as $key => $word){
    //Loop through all the replacements
    foreach($array1 as $array1key => $item){

        if($item == $key){
        //if match found replace
        $array1[$array1key] = $word;

        }
    }   
}

print_r($array1);
```